# Swift Core Data - summing value with NSExpression & NSFetchRequest

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, nsfetchrequest

Ok, so I have Core Data Entity named "ScheduledEntry" that contains few attributes. My goal is to show stuff in tableView by the sum.

Code for fetchins is:

```
func taskFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ScheduledEntry")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
return fetchRequest
```

And I was trying (without success) this to the taskFetchRequest func:

```
fetchRequest.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType()
var expressionDescription = NSExpressionDescription()
expressionDescription.expression = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "@sum.value")
expressionDescription.expressionResultType = NSAttributeType.DecimalAttributeType
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [expressionDescription]
```

So my question is - what I'm doing wrong? What is proper solution?

Comment: What problem do you have.  The syntax seems OK for Swift 2.2.  (One warning that `var expressionDescription` would be better as `let`.)

Comment: problem is that whole app is crashing on App Delegate :)

Comment: Maybe if you showed the stack trace that you get when crashing, it would be easier to guess.

Comment: If you want to use an expression description in your `propertiesToFetch`, you must specify the resultType `.DictionaryResultType` for the fetch.  NSFetchRequestResultType() defaults to `.ManagedObjectResultType`.